# How to map childs/parent class with petapoco?

Tags: orm, petapoco

I have these classes:

```
class Car {
    int ID;
    string Name;
}

class Truck : Car {
    int MaximumLoad;
}
```

I have these tables

```
Car
- ID
- Name

Truck
- CarID
- MaximumLoad
```

How could I map my classes with my table using PetaPoco ?

Answer (score 3):

If you store Car and Truck in the same table ([TPH](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/table-per-type-vs-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance.html)) you can inherit Truck from Car with minor changes to PetaPOCO source code,

table Vehicle (ID, Discriminator, Name, MaximumLoad)

in PetaPOCO.cs, add

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class DiscriminatorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public DiscriminatorAttribute(object discriminator)
    {
        Value = (int)discriminator;
    }
}

protected bool IsTPHTable<T>()
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    var a = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DiscriminatorAttribute), true);
    return a.Length > 0;
}

protected void AppendDiscriminator<T>(Sql sql)
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    var a = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DiscriminatorAttribute), true);
    sql.Append("Where Discriminator = @0", (a[0] as DiscriminatorAttribute).Value);
}

public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(Sql sql)
{
    if (IsTPHTable<T>())
        AppendDiscriminator<T>(sql);
    return Query<T>(default(T), sql);
}

// also similar AppendDiscriminator() for Update an Delete.
```

Then in your Car.cs and Truck.cs, you can write/generate code like this,

```
public enum VehicleType:int
{
    Car,
    Truck
}

[TableName("Vehicle")]
[Discriminator(VehicleType.Car)]
public class Car  
{
    [Column] 
    public int ID {get; set;}
    [Column]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public Car()
    {
        //this.Discriminator = VehicleType.Car;
    }
    public static new Car SingleOrDefault(object primaryKey) { return repo.SingleOrDefaultById<Car>(primaryKey); }
    //...
}

[Discriminator(VehicleType.Truck)]
public class Truck:Car  
{
    [Column] 
    public double MaximumLoad {get;set;}

    public Truck()
    {
        //this.Discriminator = VehicleType.Truck;
    }   
    public static new Truck SingleOrDefault(object primaryKey) { return repo.SingleOrDefaultById<Truck>(primaryKey); }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To read truck records I would create a Trucks view that combines the two tables. Or have a look at Schotime's muliple result sets :

http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2011/11/20/petapoco-multiple-result-sets/

For writes I guess you are asking "how can I write to 2 tables in one operation". Off the top of my head I would probably say I would simply perform 2 writes. I think Petapoco will ignore fields that don't map so you may be able to use your truck object for both writes.

Could easily be wrong as I haven't tested this.

Comment: I don't really like to touch anything else than my DataLayer class, these tools shouldn't change anything in your sql server or in your pocco. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I think (have not tested though) that if you do something like this..

```
repo.Fetch<Truck>(";Select car.*, truck.maximumload from car left join truck on car.id = truck.carid");
```

or

```
repo.Fetch<Truck>(";Select car.*, truck.maximumload from car left join truck on car.id = truck.carid where truck.carid = @0", truckid);
```

I would probably have called my base class vehicle rather than car, buts that's just me.

Hope that helps ?

Comment: I figured that this is not possible with petapoco : we can't specify the object type for the Insert/Update/Delete method, so if I pass a Truck, petapoco can't insert the good informations into the car table. thanks anyway, i'll have a look at dapper.