# Inheritance and Dapper.net

Tags: dapper

I decided to use Dapper.net because it seems to be doing only what I want : mapping, I don't need anything fancy , I'm just bored to handle the mapping between my datareader and my object.

My problem :

Let's say I have these class :

```
class Foo{
int ID;
string Name;
}
class Bar : Foo{
string FavoriteMoovie;
}
```

And these tables :

```
Foo 
- ID
- Name

Bar
- FooID
- FavoriteMoovie
```

So I'd like to know how I can select my Foo and Bars in the same query ?

My only idea so far is

- SELECT all the Foos that are not Bars
- then SELECT all the Bars

I can't use the overload of the method "Query" because there are just here for mapping relationships.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/8344591/75642 except that it's about Dapper?

Comment: As I said In my revious question I had to move out from petapoco because this is not possible with petapoco. As I said here, I have a solution with Dapper, but I'm looking for a better one with this tool

Answer (score 2):

Very hacky, but this probably works.

```
db.Query<Bar, object, Foo>("select * from Foo left join Bar on FooID = ID",
 (bar,ignore) => 
   bar.FavoriteMoovie == null ? bar : new Foo{ID = bar.ID, Name = bar.Name});
```

Disadvantage is that it creates a couple of intermediate objects that it could do without.

Other options are to simply select `Bar` objects and then use the same trick to filter out the Foos or select a dynamic and then convert to the correct class.

Personally I would not query twice just to handle this, unless you are allowing for `NULL` FavoriteMoovie, in which case you have no choice but to either complicate the query or select twice.

Comment: I did a multiple select to handle this "SELECT * INTO #temp FROM Foo ; SELECT * FROM #temp where not exists(..) select * from #temp innter join bar on ..."

Comment: I think this was supposed to be `bar.FavoriteMoovie != null`?

Answer (score 1):

in the case when one table per hierarchy TPH, it is easy to get all concrete childs Class, especially if the BaseClass is abstract

```
abstract class BaseValue
{
    public BaseValue()
        : this(0, 0, string.Empty)
    {
    }

    public BaseValue(int id, double value, string dimension)
    {
        Id = id;
        TypeName = GetType().Name;
        Dimension = dimension;
        _value = value;
    }

    protected double _value;

    public double RawValue
    {
        get { return _value;  }
    }

    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public string TypeName { get; protected set; }

    public string Dimension { get; set; }

}

abstract class BaseValue<T> : BaseValue
    where T : struct
{
    public BaseValue()
        : this(0, default(T), string.Empty)
    { }

    public BaseValue(int id, T value, string dimension)
        : base(id, 0, dimension)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
                return (dynamic)(float)_value;
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
                return (dynamic)(bool)(_value > 0 ? true : false);
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
                return (dynamic)(int)_value;
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(TimeSpan))
                return (dynamic)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_value);
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
                return (dynamic)new DateTime((long)_value);
            else
                return (dynamic)_value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
                _value = (float)(object)value;
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
                _value = (bool)(object)value ? 1 : 0;
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
                _value = (int)(object)value;
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(TimeSpan))
                _value = ((TimeSpan)(object)value).TotalSeconds;
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
                _value = ((DateTime)(object)value).Ticks;
            else
                _value = (double)(object)value;
        }
    }
}

class IntValue : BaseValue<int>
{
    public IntValue()
        : this(0, 0, string.Empty)
    { }

    public IntValue(int id, int value, string dimension)
        : base(id, value, dimension)
    { }
}

class BoolValue : BaseValue<bool>
{
    public BoolValue()
        : this(0, false, string.Empty)
    { }

    public BoolValue(int id, bool value, string dimension)
        : base(id, value, dimension)
    { }
}

class FloatValue : BaseValue<float>
{
    public FloatValue()
        : this(0, 0, string.Empty)
    { }

    public FloatValue(int id, float value, string dimension)
        : base(id, value, dimension)
    { }
}

class TimeSpanValue : BaseValue<TimeSpan>
{
    public TimeSpanValue()
        : this(0, TimeSpan.MinValue, string.Empty)
    { }

    public TimeSpanValue(int id, TimeSpan value, string dimension)
        : base(id, value, dimension)
    { }
}

class DateTimeValue : BaseValue<DateTime>
{
    public DateTimeValue()
        : this(0, DateTime.Now, string.Empty)
    { }

    public DateTimeValue(int id, DateTime value, string dimension)
        : base(id, value, dimension)
    { }
}
```

and Repository select from TPH table:

```
class Repository
{
    public IEnumerable<BaseValue> GetAll()
    {
        IEnumerable<BaseValue> values = null;

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            cn.Open();

            const string query = "SELECT Id, TypeName, RawValue, Dimension FROM Values";

            values = cn.Query<BaseValue, object, BaseValue>(query,
                (value, ignore) =>
                {
                    BaseValue child = null;

                    if (value.TypeName == "IntValue")
                        child = new IntValue(value.Id, (int)value.RawValue, value.Dimension);
                    else if (value.TypeName == "BoolValue")
                        child = new BoolValue(value.Id, value.RawValue > 0, value.Dimension);
                    else if (value.TypeName == "FloatValue")
                        child = new FloatValue(value.Id, (float)value.RawValue, value.Dimension);
                    else if (value.TypeName == "TimeSpanValue")
                        child = new TimeSpanValue(value.Id, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value.RawValue), value.Dimension);
                    else if (value.TypeName == "DateTimeValue")
                        child = new DateTimeValue(value.Id, new DateTime((long)value.RawValue), value.Dimension);

                    return child;
                });

            cn.Close();
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```